# NativeScript TextView does not allow multiline text on Android

Tags: nativescript

On an Android device, I am using a TextView as:

```html
<TextView id="txtMessage" class="data" text="{{ formData.message }}" height="150" />
```

The problem is that when the user presses the return key on the keyboard the caret does not go to a new line.  The text wraps if you type a long line, but I cannot make it go down on a separate line.  I thought that this was the default behavior.

How can I make it allow multi-line text?

Thank you.

Comment: TextField use. ha

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you suggesting to use TextField?  In this case, the keyboard does not display the return key, it is showing the return type key (Done, Next, etc) which does not allow multiline text

Comment: Disregard my comment - I got the two mixed up. I'm using TextView and works just fine. maybe add textWrap="true" in the xml file

Comment: I tried that.  no luck though.

Comment: After some searching I found this:  https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/1273.  Upgrading is not an options for me at this point.  Does anyone have another idea?